# Web Server and VPN on same machine

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, web-server

I have a domain, lets call it `test.com` thats pointing to IP `260.0.0.10`, this is my home external ip.

On this IP I have an webserver (Wildfly) and an VPN client (AirVPN). My IP on the VPN client is `300.0.0.10`.

Wildfly is behaving as I want, It answers to the calls of `260.0.0.10`.

If I look for my external IP in Google it is `300.0.0.10`, how I expect it to be, everything fine until now.

**1.** My other programs do use the VPN but, will this affect the webserver?

**2.** As far as I understand, this is like having 2 external IP adresses, except that `260.0.0.10` goes through my ISP and allows port forwarding while `300.0.0.10` still goes through my ISP but does not allow port forwarding (nor am I interested in it since vpns would be useless lol), is this correct?

**3.** Is there any chance for the trafic on `300.0.0.10` to know that `260.0.0.10` even exists? I mean, while using the VPN to browse the web can it be possible for lets say Chrome to find a relationship between `300.0.0.10` and `260.0.0.10`?

**4.** Would using VPN and WebServer at the same time affect web ranking / indexing?

Comment: That 300 IP octet is rather unique... Your problem is unclear, do you have a problem or are you asking for general advice?

Comment: @Tim hahah, just didnt want to use any kind of real ips, asking for thing I do not understand...

Comment: Web server and VPN server on the same machine are fine, so long as they run on different ports, which would be standard. You have one external IP address. What exactly are you trying to achieve? A VPN into your home computer?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to VPN the answer is that you have to setup routing properly.  In your case you may need policy and or source based routing to control which interface (vpn or physical) is used for outgoing packets.

Setups like this can get very complex, and often requires a really good understanding of routing.